# Theorem about SDR

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Theorem Let $A_1,\ldots,A_n$ be subsets of a set $X$. Suppose that, for some positive integer $m$, we have $|A(J)|\ge|J|-m\mbox{ for all }J\subseteq\{1,\ldots,n\}$, where $A(J)=\bigcup\limits_{j\in J} A_j$. Then it is possible to find $n-m$ of the sets $A_1,\ldots, A_n$ which have a SDR. I know I should take $m$ elements and add them to all the sets $A_i$ but I don't know the rest

Comment: You need to enclose the $\LaTeX$ expressions in dollar signs; also, use `\{` and `\}` to get curly braces.

Comment: Am I the only one who doesn't know what SDR means?

Comment: @Randall: System of distinct representatives, also known as a transversal: it’s an injective function that picks out a member of each of the sets $A_k$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I’ll point you in the right direction. Let $M$ be a set of $m$ objects not contained in any of the sets $A_1,\ldots,A_n$. For $k=1,\ldots,n$ let $B_k=A_k\cup M$.

- Show that $|B(J)|\ge|J|$ for each $J\subseteq\{1,\ldots,n\}$.
- Apply Hall’s theorem to $\{B_1,\ldots,B_n\}$.
- What is the largest number of sets $B_k$ that can have their representives in $M$? That leaves at least how many that have their representatives in $A_k$?